# Add Columns to A CSV File

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm trying to add a column to a CSV using PowerShell and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but it's removing all data from the CSV file instead of adding the column.

```
Import-Csv 'C:\folder\file.csv' |
    Select-Object *,@{Name='Source';Expression={'test'}} |
    Export-Csv 'C:\folder\file.csv'
```

Comment: What is the contents of `file.csv`?

Comment: names and addresses, so it has firstname, secondname, address1 ect

Comment: can you just put two lines screenshot of csv by changing data should be more helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write content back to the same file make sure that reading the file and parsing its content is completed *before* you start writing to it. Failing to do so will cause the file to be truncated, as you observed (or throw an error, depending on the cmdlet).

```
(Import-Csv 'C:\folder\file.csv') |
    Select-Object *,@{Name='Source';Expression={'test'}} |
    Export-Csv 'C:\folder\file.csv'
```

Note the parentheses around the `Import-Csv` statement.